# When would you rather use one over the other?

Tags: adjectives

Thank you so much all for supporting and wrote back to my previous question?

They are 15-year-old girls

They are 15-year-olds

Comment: They have the same meaning. Unless you want to bring emphasis to the fact that they're **girls**, you can pick and choose. This question has already been asked. xD

Answer (score 2):

Use *They are 15-year-olds* if it is a group of mixed gender, or if the gender is not relevant to what you are trying to communicate.

Use *They are 15-year-old girls* if it is important that you communicate that the gender of the group is entirely female.

Answer (score 1):

They are synonymous in meaning.

15-year-old **girls** brings emphasis to the fact that they are **girls**, while 15-year-olds is more ambiguous. Apart from where the emphasis lies, you could pick and choose which you employ.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the group of girls as a compound adjective or noun it takes "They are 15-year-olds". On the other hand, it'll be *They are 15-year-old girls* if you take it as a separate qualifier.

A common rule applies that when it is a counted thing serving as an adjective, the count's object is singular. *A 10-hour game*, "A 6-foot tall" and so on. Similarly, when it is not that case, the pluralization happens this way -"those 22-year-old" and so on.

Comment: You bring up an interesting point about hyphens. That said, "those 22 year old" needs a hyphen somewhere. If I'm talking about a group of young trees, I'd say, "Those 22 year-old trees were planted last year; I planted two dozen, but two of them died." On the other hand, if I'm talking about a group of people, I'd say, "Those 22-year-old kids seem like they're looking for trouble" (or, "Those 22-year-olds are acting very mature for their age").

Comment: @J.R. Thta's true. I just discussed in a session with my teammates. The session was about hyphens. Hyphens are put when they affect the nouns. *Those 22-year-old girls were pretty* OVER *My pug is 12 years old* where we don't put hyphen. Edited and corrected. Thanks